# How make text file into desired format in CSV using Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, csv, numpy, text

I am currently working on generating some graphs and such for a dataset that I have generated using another Python script. The goal is to have these graphs generated automatically after running the other program so manual editing is not an option here.

The original code generates a text file in the format of:
center_freq 791125000.0 freq 790625000.0 power_db 0.211535437034 noise_floor_db -100.913246571

There are approximately 50 of these lines that come from the code with different results each time
I have managed to separate this into a list of each individual item and make it into a CSV file in which each string or integer is in its own row.

However, working with numpy it seems it would be easier if there was only the titles for the category at the top of each column followed by all of the data. I am not sure how to modify from its current state, this is my code as of now:

To take the textfile and generate a list:

```
     import sys

     open_file = open("usrp_official_jamming.txt","r")
     f = open("datafiles.txt","w+")
     lst = list()
     sys.stdout = f


     for line in open_file:
            words = line.split()

     for word in words:
            lst.append(word)

     n = 27
     lst2 = lst[n:-1]
     print(lst2)
```

Then to take the list and generate the CSV:

```
    import csv
    from itertools import izip_longest

    with open('datafiles.txt') as f:
        with open('usrpcsv.csv', 'wb') as csv_file:
            writer = csv.writer(csv_file)
            for line in f.readlines():
                 data = line.split(', ')
                 chunks= [data[x:x+8] for x in xrange(0, len(data), 8)]
                 for chunk in chunks:
                     writer.writerow(chunk)
```